# Change iframe contents using an external anchor?

Tags: html, iframe, twitch

I'm trying to make a "media hub" of sorts for the streaming team that I'm a part of. I want an iframe that loads the initial stream (for the purpose of testing, its my own, but the final would be our group channel), and when one of our usernames on the page is clicked I want it to load that specific stream into the iframe.

I've tried using this so far, but I'm fairly certain it will take more than HTML to pull off.

```html
<div>
 <iframe name="stream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/marcusraven86/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe>
</div>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" onClick="loadintoIframe('stream,'http://www.twitch.tv/marcusraven86/embed');">MarcusRaven86</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" onClick="loadintoIframe('stream,'http://www.twitch.tv/dragonbornmonocle/embed');">DragonbornMonocle</a></li>
<ul>
```

The iframe is still relatively new to me, but I'm usually quick to understand with a good example. Am I at least heading in the right direction?

Comment: I think you are missing an ' behind the `stream` in the `OnClick` finctions

Comment: Wow, that's an obvious mistake. Thanks for that. It still didn't work though. I click between the two stream anchors and nothing changes.

Comment: Can you maybe update your code snippet so that we can see? It must be `onClick="loadIntoIframe('stream','http://www.twich.tv/...')"` - and your `loadIntoIframe` function isn't uninteresting too

Comment: Actually, I think you just cleared up my issue. I didn't realize the "loadIntoIframe" was a function. I found this in an example somewhere. I'll look further into that example to see if the function is available. I haven't messed with javascript much, so we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Okay, I solved it a completely different way, and I'm really surprised it was this easy.
`<iframe name="stream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/marcusraven86/embed"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/dragonbornmonocle/embed" target="stream">DragonbornMonocle</a>`
...and so on.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Please post the way you resolved your problem in an answer and accept it so that future users can learn from you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sold this by doing this, name the iframe, then set anchor source to the new embed link and the target to the iframe's name:

```
<iframe name="stream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/marcusraven86/embed"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/dragonbornmonocle/embed" target="stream">DragonbornMonocle</a>
...
```

And so on for other streams.